# Enviar atributo de elemento a otro html jquery

Tags: html, jquery, post

Tengo un html llamado "usuario.html"

en el cual tengo un form... que contiene el siguiente elemento.

```
<input type="hidden" id="idusuario">
```

Ese elemento cambia el "value" dependiendo de ciertos valores.

Lo que yo quiero es saber si con jQuery, se puede llevar ese atributo, a otro html, x ejemplo "consulta.html" donde también tengo un elemento.

```
<input type="hidden" id="idusuarioconsulta">
```

Desde ya, **Muchas gracias**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución rápida que se me ocurre es que obtengas el valor del primer `input`, lo guardes en **local storage** o incluso una **cookie** y cuando manipules el dato en el segundo `input` borres el rastro para evitar cualquier tipo de problema.

### Por ejemplo:

**HTML DEL PRIMER INPUT**

```
localStorage.setItem('identificador', 'valor');
```

**HTML DEL SEGUNDO INPUT**

```
var yourNewVar = localStorage.getItem('identificador');
// Elimina todos los elementos
localStorage.clear();
```

Todo esto con JavaScript o jQuery dentro del archivo respectivo.

Te dejo la documentación en español de Mozilla [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)